# How to resolve iOS custom keyboard extension issue?

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard

[image]

I did use a build script in the keyboard extension target with the following to resolve the issue but my keyboard extension does not show up after uploading the build to Testflight. I also set the Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries to Yes for app and No for keyboard extension.

```
cd "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"
if [[ -d "Frameworks" ]]; then 
   rm -fr Frameworks
fi
```